# Android intent sometimes "handled" instead of ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, action

My app is supposed to handle shared texts. For example URLs from the amazon app. So I added the following intent-filter to my main activity:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

In my onCreate function of my activity, I'm processing the intent like so:

```
        intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
                if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
                    onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(1);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is, that sometimes the onCreate function isn't called following a sharing action.
I checked the onResume method, and indeed that's what is called. The problem is that the intents action isn't "ACTION_SEND", but is packagename.handled and doesn't contain the needed information.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `android:documentLaunchMode` and `android:launchMode` in the manifest for the activity?

Answer (score 8):

If your activity already exists, depending on `Intent` flags and `<activity>` attributes, that existing activity instance may be reused. Override `onNewIntent()` to get the `Intent` being delivered to an existing activity instance that is causing it to be brought back to the foreground. Look in there for your `ACTION_SEND` values.

Comment: In my case, onNewIntent() isn't called either.